# How do graphs differ from functions in classical mathematical logic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The following is from a textbook "A First Course in Logic An Introduction to Model Theory Proof Theory Computability and Complexity."

> The graph of f: A → B is the subset of A × B consisting of all ordered pairs ( a,b) with f(a)=b.
>
> The notation f : A → B expresses that f is a function from set A to a subset of set B. This means that, given any a ∈ A as input, f yields at most one output f(a)∈ B. It is possible that, given a ∈ A, f yields no output

The only discernible difference I see here is that a graph is a function without undefined values for f(a) = b.

Also, I have no clue what this means:

> If A happens to be B^n for some n ∈ N, then we say that f is a function on B and n is the arity of f. In this case, the graph of f is an (n +1)-ary relation on B.

So, for intance, an object of A (x,y,z) maps to an object of B (x,y,z) for all A and B? If so, what is an example of such a relation?

Thank you.

EDIT:
The textbook always says that inverses of functions don't always define functions. I imagine this is because of the possibility of undefined values f(a) that mean that f(b) would not map to such an a? If that is so, do inverses of graphs always define a function? (Or a graph, more specifically?)

Comment: They don't, the usual distinction between a function and its graph is made in both places. The second definition is different. It means that if $A$ is a set of $n$-tuples of elements from $B$ then they would cal it an $n$-ar function *on $B$*, which is usually said of relations but not functions. E.g. we would call a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, not an $n$-ar function on $\mathbb{R}$. The inverses do not always define functions because several different values can be mapped into the same one, and the inverse will have no way to pick just one.